# Dinamizar língua para placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Eu faço uma requisição ajax para buscar no banco para trazer a configuração de linguagem, tipo, PT-BR, EN, e assim vai...

Quero que os placeholders sejam alterados conforme a linguagem escolhida. Por exemplo, em vez de ficar `placeholder='Digite seu usuario'`, gostaria que ficasse `placeholder='Enter your username'` e assim vai...

Para tags do tipo bloco (tipo p, div etc.) eu manipulo assim `$("#memberArea").html(data.pt.member_area);`, e aí funciona perfeitamente, porém, para placeholder não sei...

Existe alguma forma de manipular isso via jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim. O `placeholder` é um atributo do elemento. Logo, você poderá alterá-lo:

```js
function teste() {
 $("#teste").attr("placeholder","Enter your username");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Digite seu usuario" type="text" id="teste" />
<input type="button" value="alterar placeholder p/ inglês" onclick="teste()" />
```